# PHP search array in MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array that contain list of users ID's and i need to go over on all my "users" table in the DB, to return only the numbers that the array contain, what is the best way?

```
<?php
$users_ids = $_REQUEST["users_ids"];

$myArray = explode('|', $users_ids);
print_r($myArray);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following:

```
$users_ids = $_REQUEST["users_ids"];
$users_ids_array = array_map('intval',explode('|', $users_ids)) ;

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (" . implode(',', $users_ids_array) . ")" ;
```

The code above will generate a mysql such that only those user ids are retrieved:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN (
    234 , # an example user_id
    545 , # an example user_id
    565   # an example user_id
)
```

*Please note the `array_map` function above to secure the `$_REQUEST["users_ids"]` variable, making sure the user ids are only integers, and not a dangerous string such as `" 233) ; DELETE FROM users ; # "` --> (in this case `array_map` prevents SQL injection)*

Answer (score 0):

In your select statement, use the IN clause. To construct the statement, implode the array into a comma separated list (instead of vertical bars). If your array contains 1,2,3,4 the resulting SQL statement might look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE user_id in (1,2,3,4)
```